# Electric cable for bicycles

Tags: wiring, wire

I am using dynamo on my bicycle to power the lights, as I hate using batteries. This serves me OK, apart from the fact I have constant problems with the end of cables.

The end of the copper braid (few cm) becomes whitish and stiff after some time and turns to powder when touching it.  Which means I have to constantly cut the wire and repair the problem.

I wonder, are there any special electric cables resistant to atmospheric influences, especially water, or I just had a bad luck picking low quality cable?

Comment: Indeed looks like a low quality cable to me, that is not to say that a "better" cable can handle moisture so much better. I usually solder the copper ends and that often helps. You could also try **vaseline** as that repels moisture. If you have no vaseline but you do have grease (for ball bearings) then try that.

Comment: I tried soldering, but braid corroded behind soldering, even few cm under the rubber/plastic protection.  Never tried vaseline, but I suppose its layer has to be constantly refreshed?

Comment: *but I suppose its layer has to be constantly refreshed?* No, it as long as it isn't removed it should need no maintenance. Ideally you should protect the wires + vaseline with some heat-shrink tubing or (duct)tape.

Comment: Look for tinned copper rather than plain : it is somewhat less prone to corrosion (aka "black death" in marine wiring) and may delay the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tinned copper wire and high quality terminals. Tinned copper wire is much more resistant to corrosion and is commonly used in environments where moisture and corrosion can be an issue, such as in vehicles.

I would not recommend soldering as that has a tendency to break due to vibration and movement at the transition between the rigid (soldered) and flexible parts of the cable.

Comment: Yes I noticed myself that transition between soldered and unsoldered is usually the weak point so I stopped soldering.  Tinned copper sounds like a sound solution.

Comment: You definitely want to pursue quality terminals.  Something with a coating for outside environment exposure. There should be plenty as automotive have to deal with this. (being an automotive part does not make it automatically able to handle a harsh outside environment)

Answer (score 0):

If the connections are exposed to the weather, they are going to corrode. A better plan is to find a way to cover them and keep moisture out. Heat Shrink tubing is probably best, along with periodic spritzing with a water displacement product like WD-40.

Answer (score 0):

[image] [image]

*Spade or ring crimp terminals.*

These are crimped onto the ends of your wire and may provide a solution if your dynamo (it's really an AC alternator, not a DC dynamo) has suitable terminals.

Comment: I tried that too.  The problem is that copper braid corrodes anyway, even few cm under the rubber/plastic protection.

Comment: It's time for a photo, I think.